# Tensorflow retrain.py Image directory not found error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying out Tensorflow for Poets from [here](https://datanonymous.wordpress.com/image-classification-using-tensorflow/) which retrains the last later of Inception on Ubuntu 14.04 CPU

following the guide I ran this code

```
    python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
–bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks \
–how_many_training_steps 500 \
–model_dir=tf_files/inception \
–output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
–output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
–image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos
```

and I got the following error

```
Image directory '' not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 774, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 671, in main
    class_count = len(image_lists.keys())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys
```

Knowing this issue relates to where my images are stored, I have them placed in the home folder which applies correctly to the last command `image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos`

So now my question is why am I getting this error even though the image directory is correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at line 774, where the error occurs, it is about summary directory, not image_dir.

You will need to set the summary directory here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L928

Comment: Thank you! i will give it a try!

Comment: can you explain in brief on how to set summary directory ! @Yao Zhang

Comment: You can set it with flag FLAGS.summaries_dir: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L1039

Answer (score 1):

retrain.py now exists in the following location now :

```
github.com/tensorflow/hub/raw/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py
```

instead of

```
tensorflow/examples/image_retraining
```

you can use this:

```
curl -LO https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/raw/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py python label_image.py \
--graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb --labels=/tmp/output_labels.txt \

--input_layer=Placeholder \

--output_layer=final_result \

--image=$HOME/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg
```

Ref:
https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining

Comment: Also try putting "" for mentioning the path for example: python retrain.py --image_dir="tf_files/data", else it might through the error dir not found or ERROR:tensorflow:Must set flag --image_dir

Answer (score 0):

**Your code block is missing the double hyphen. So, try this:**

```
python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
–-bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks \
–-how_many_training_steps 500 \
–-model_dir=tf_files/inception \
–-output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
–-output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
–-image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos
```

Answer (score 0):

Pleas use the absolute path to fix the issue. For example `/home/pi/Desktop/hub/retrained_data/dataset`

Answer (score 0):

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hFte7dNUZGVukuR0OY02t0atJgMzn6oc#scrollTo=Bl-yFZqKeezp&forceEdit=true&offline=true&sandboxMode=true

**Step 0**

Replace retrain.py with downloading file from following link and uploading it to same folder in Google drive.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/hub/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

**Step 1**

Go to this link :

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hFte7dNUZGVukuR0OY02t0atJgMzn6oc#scrollTo=Bl-yFZqKeezp&forceEdit=true&offline=true&sandboxMode=true

**Step 2**

Go to chapter Two

**Step 3**

**Worked by adding two lines as given following before the script section : LOL**

**It's a LOL that just added following two lines and it worked before script section and it worked.**

**Two Lines:**

```
if not os.path.isdir("../Pokemons-subset"):

     print('Error')
```

**Script Section:**

```
 %run scripts/retrainn.py   \

   --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks   \

   --how_many_training_steps=4000   \

   --model_dir=tf_files/models/   \

   --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/mobilenet_0.50_160   \

   --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb   \

   --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt   \

   --learning_rate=0.01   \

   --architecture=mobilenet_0.50_160   \

   --image_dir=../Pokemons-subset \

   --flip_left_right \

   --random_crop=10 \

   --random_scale=10 \

   --random_brightness=10
```